# Rails - group and .count.to_sql not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'd like to run `.to_sql` on activerecord query `ahoy_visits.group(query).select('DISTINCT ahoy_visits.user_id').count` to get sql query.

However trying `ahoy_visits.group(query).select('DISTINCT ahoy_visits.user_id').count.to_sql` gives error undefined method `to_sql' for #Hash:0x000000036c798988

I tried select('COUNT(*)') or .select(Arel.star.count)

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to get the `to_sql` on a normal `count` or `group.count` since `count` immediately executes the query. You can approximate it with some Arel:

```rb
Ahoy::Visit.group("os")
  .select(:os, Ahoy::Visit.arel_table[:user_id].count(true))
  .to_sql
```

Which returns

```sql
SELECT "ahoy_visits"."os", COUNT(DISTINCT "ahoy_visits"."user_id") 
FROM "ahoy_visits" 
GROUP BY "ahoy_visits"."os"
```

`count(true)` makes the count distinct in Arel.

Removing the `to_sql` on that code will run the query, but you won't get the expected `group.count` hash results. If you want to convert it back into the hash format that AR gives you, you would do a `to_h`:

```rb
Ahoy::Visit.group("os")
  .select(:os, Ahoy::Visit.arel_table[:user_id].count(true))
  .to_h { |v| [v.os, v.count] }
```

This would run the same SQL and give you the same result hash as:

```rb
Ahoy::Visit.select(:user_id).group(:os).distinct.count
```