# Rails: How can I use .to_sql on a .select() request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have an ActiveRecord request:

```
Post.all.select { |p| Date.today < p.created_at.weeks_since(2) }
```

And I want to be able to see what SQL request this produces using `.to_sql`

The error I get is: `NoMethodError: undefined method 'to_sql'`

TIA!

Comment: `select` in this expression contains a ruby block so it's impossible to represent it in SQL (because this part doesn't run in the database)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**ISSUE**

There are 2 types of `select` when it comes to `ActiveRecord` objects, from the [Docs](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-select)

1. `select` with a Block.

> First: takes a block so it can be used just like `Array#select`.
> This will build an array of objects from the database for the scope, converting them into an array and iterating through them using `Array#select`.

This is what you are using right now. This implementation will load every post instantiate a `Post` object and then iterating over each `Post` using `Array#select` to filter the results into an `Array`. This is highly inefficient, cannot be chained with other AR semantics (e.g. `where`,`order`,etc.) and will cause very long lags at scale. (This is also what is causing your error because `Array` does not have a `to_sql` method)

2. `select` with a list of columns (or a String if you prefer)

> Second: Modifies the SELECT statement for the query so that only certain fields are retrieved...

This version is unnecessary in your case as you do not wish to limit the columns returned by the query to posts.

**Suggested Resolution:**

Instead what you are looking for is a WHERE clause to filter the records at the database level before returning them to the ORM.

Your current filter is (X < Y + 2)

```
 Date.today < p.created_at.weeks_since(2)
```

which means Today's Date is less than Created At plus 2 Weeks.

We can invert this criteria to make it easier to query by switching this to Today's Date minus 2 weeks is less than Created At. (X - 2 < Y)

```
Date.today.weeks_ago(2) < p.created_at
```

This is equivalent to `p.created_at > Date.today.weeks_ago(2)` which we can convert to a where clause using standard ActiveRecord query methods:

```
Post.where(created_at: Date.today.weeks_ago(2)...)
```

This will result in SQL like:

```
SELECT 
  posts.*
FROM 
  posts.* 
WHERE 
  posts.created_at > '2022-10-28'
```

**Notes:**

- `created_at` is a TimeStamp so it might be better to use `Time.now` vs `Date.today`.
- Additional concerns may be involved from a time zone perspective since you will be performing date/time specific comparisons.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `to_sql` on a relation. `select` executes the query and gives you the result, and on the result you don't have `to_sql` method.

There are similar [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71804034/rails-group-and-count-to-sql-not-working) which you can look at as they offer some alternatives.

Comment: "select executes the query" - Not necessarily. It depends on what `select` is it, from `Enumerable` or active record. `Post.select(:created_at)` doesn't execute a query, for example (and you can call `.to_sql` on this)